# htaccess rewrite for routing from a sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been using this `.htaccess` file for enabling the [grav](https://getgrav.org/) Cms for a few sites:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/grav/
RewriteRule ^$ /grav [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /grav/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works flawlessly as long the site is at the document root.

Now, I have a new site that starts in `2020/` and has Grav installed in `2020/grav`.

I modified the above `.htaccess` to be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2020/grav/
RewriteRule ^2020$ /2020/grav [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^2020/(.*)$ /2020/grav/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This `.htaccess` file is located in `/2020/`.

While in the first case the url is left as is and Grav gets the rest of the url as parameters, in the second case (`2020/`) the url changes to `/2020/grav`, which is not what I want?

I wanted to check if it was a Grav issue and I've setup a simple test case, with the above `.htaccess` file and a `grav/` directory with only an `index.php` file in there and I got the same result.

Any hint on how I have to modify the `.htaccess` file to get `2020/abc` to stay as is in the url bar and at the same time have `Grav` to get the `abc` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this code in `2020/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ grav/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!grave/)(.+)$ grav/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!grave/)` is negative lookahead condition that will skip match if match already starts with `grave/`

Comment: it does work for a small test site i've setup for this issue: <https://libregraphicsmeeting.org/2030/htaccess.php> works for <https://libregraphicsmeeting.org/2030/hello> in the real site <https://libregraphicsmeeting.org/2020/> it does not seem to work (you can check <https://libregraphicsmeeting.org/2020/htaccess.php> )

Comment: no, that sounds wrong... the .htaccess does work, otherwise i would not have any redirection... instead of a wrong redirection. also, grav would not work at all...

Comment: the administrator confirms that it should be apache... (he says taht you're seeing the TLS offloader, which uses nginx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198955/discussion-between-a-l-e-and-anubhava).

Comment: After a long chat discussion, the proposed rule seems to be the good one. I will try to go through the Grav to see where it fails at correctly handling the .htaccess redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was about getting it to work with an `.htaccess`.

@anubhava gave a very good answer for the general case. But it sadly *was not enough* for Grav.

I got some more help in the Grav forums and at the end of a long journey Ole found out that the question has been asked in their forums a long time ago and a solution was found!

The `/2020/.haccess` can be simply defined as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2020/grav/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2020/grav/$1
```

But what one need is to add a couple of configurations in the `/2020/grav/user/config/system.yaml` file:

```
custom_base_url: 'http://domain.tld/2020'
session:
  path: /2020
```

You can find a more detailed question and Ole's reply [in the Grav forums](https://discourse.getgrav.org/t/on-serving-a-site-on-http-mydomain-2020-with-grav-in-2020-grav/10175)